# Is there a way to remove all the XMP MetaData in iText 7?

Tags: itext7

I'm trying to remove all the XMP MetaData in iText 7. It seems like it should remove, but when I write it back all the old data is still there. I tried this:

```
var pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader("document.pdf"), new PdfWriter("document-new.pdf"));
pdfDoc.SetXmpMetadata(XMPMetaFactory.Create());
pdfDoc.Close();
```

We just want to make sure that all possible metadata is removed as these are for papers and we don't want reviewers to know who's paper if they hid some metadata somewhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

My answer to this is walk away from the computer. I'm not sure if it was a caching issue or what, but I restarted my computer of the weekend, opened up Visual Studio with the same code and it started to work. Yeah for weekends!

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would like to mention that there are a ton of ways to hide information in a PDF file - and you cannot guarantee that all the traces are removed by removing metadata. However, this is indeed a necessary precaution.

The reason why the metadata is not removed with your code is that the information about author, title and similar things can be stored in metadata as well as in the so-called `Info dictionary`. Moreover, information in info dictionary and metadata should stay in sync - and this is what iText handles for you.

Therefore, to make sure the author, title etc are removed, remove that information from Info dictionary as well (I'm using `N/A` here, you can use empty string if you like):

```
pdfDocument.getDocumentInfo().setAuthor("N/A");
pdfDocument.getDocumentInfo().setCreator("N/A");
pdfDocument.getDocumentInfo().setKeywords("N/A");
pdfDocument.getDocumentInfo().setSubject("N/A");
pdfDocument.getDocumentInfo().setTitle("N/A");
pdfDocument.setXmpMetadata(XMPMetaFactory.create());
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey for the info. I didn't include the whole code that I had, but I do have that part also that you listed above. I'm not sure what the heck happened, but after a weekend of shutting down the computer, restarting it everything is working :shrug: